# knpsnappy bundle symfony2 cannot add headers and footers on multiple pages

Tags: symfony

Below is my code to add headers and footers to generate pdf, I don't know here I'm doing it wrong.Please help!

```
$html = $this->renderView('CoreBundle:PdfGenerator:generate.html.twig', array(
            'userId'  => $userId,
        ));
        $snappy = $this->get('knp_snappy.pdf');
        $snappy->setOption('header-html', $this->container->get('templating.helper.assets')->getUrl('bundles/core/pdfHtml/header.html'));
        $snappy->setOption('footer-html', $this->container->get('templating.helper.assets')->getUrl('bundles/core/pdfHtml/footer.html'));
        //echo $request->getHost().$this->container->get('templating.helper.assets')->getUrl('bundles/core/pdfHtml/header.html'); die();


        echo $html; die();
        return new Response(
            $snappy->getOutputFromHtml($html),
            200,
            array(
                'Content-Type'          => 'application/pdf',
                'Content-Disposition'   => 'attachment; filename="file.pdf"'
            )
        );
```

Answer (score 0):

http://www.michaelperrin.fr/2016/02/17/generating-pdf-files-with-symfony/

Follow this, I got my stuff working

```
    $header = $this->renderView('FamilyHealthDischargeSummaryBundle:ExportPdf:header.html.twig');
    $body = $this->renderView('FamilyHealthDischargeSummaryBundle:ExportPdf:body.html.twig', $data);

    $snappy = $this->get('knp_snappy.pdf');
    $snappy->setOption('header-html', $header);

    return new Response(
        $snappy->getOutputFromHtml($body), 200,
        [
            'Content-Type' => 'application/pdf',
            'Content-Disposition' => 'attachment; filename=' . $file2 . '.pdf',
        ]
    );
}
```